# Force both WWW and HTTPS in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I searched stackoverflow but my htaccess file is a little different than what I saw. Here's what I currently have:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I've seen a couple of different methods for forcing HTTPS in an htaccess file, and both worked for me on their own, but getting both www + https no matter WHAT someone types into their browser is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you're after.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark since it solved your issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between these two methods:

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`code`

and

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

Comment: It's just checking for the use of the protocol rather than checking for the port. I prefer checking for https rather than 80. Servers can run on other ports.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```